# VLOOKUP with criterion in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, worksheet-function

I have a table A that contains ID (i.e. `SR1000`). Also a table B with two rows, another ID (i.e. `C-1`) and text on the second row.

I was trying to use VLOOKUP using the ID on table A to return ID on Table B if ID from Table A is somewhere in the text of column 2 in table B.

```
Table A
SR1000
SR1001  

Table B
C-1|dummy text
C-2|dummy SR1000 dummy
```

So it should return `C-2` when looking for `SR1000`.

Is VBA my only option? Trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If your data is structured as it appears, you would need `Hlookup()`, not `Vlookup()`, correct?

Comment: That did the trick @pnuts, please make a formal answer to award it to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the formula:

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH("*"&B4&"*",G:G,0))
```

has been deemed fit for purpose and by way of explanation this was based on assumed locations as below:

[image: SO2932641 example]